# maven compiling errors (1.3 up to 1.7)

Tags: java, maven-2

I am trying to compile a project via maven (2.. version)
And get a PACK of errors that looks like

```
(use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
/home/moonsearch/moonsearch/./site/src/com/myPrj/site/tags/MyTag.java:[32,37] error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.3
```

I have wrote an 1.7 version in POM like this:

```
<plugin><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
</configuration></plugin>
```

But still get this damned messages. Really stuck in it.

after addition of version (`<version>2.0.8</version>`) it crashed before compilation - 
(I have got a version number from mvn -v)

```
    [WARNING] Skipping jpp repository file:///usr/share/maven2/repository in vanilla mode
Downloading: file:///usr/share/maven2/bootstrap_repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.8/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.8.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.8/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.8.pom
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.8/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.8.pom
[WARNING] Skipping jpp repository file:///usr/share/maven2/repository in vanilla mode
Downloading: file:///usr/share/maven2/bootstrap_repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.8/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.8.pom
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.0.8/maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.8.pom

 [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


    Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

    Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

      org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.0.8

    from the specified remote repositories:
      java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
      __jpp_repo__ (file:///usr/share/maven2/repository),
      bootstrap_repo (file:///usr/share/maven2/bootstrap_repo),
      central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
     for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin
```

And this is how the repository defined in my POM

```
<repository>
<id>java.net</id>
<url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: There is no such version, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use with maven 3.1.1

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

BTW There was no 2.0.8 version so I suspect there is a version problem see
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-compiler-plugin%22

Comment: /opt/maven/bin]$ mvn -v
/usr/java/jdk
Maven version: 2.0.8

Comment: @curiousity That is your version of maven, but there is no such version of the `maven-compiler-plugin` which has its own versions.

Answer (score 0):

Put a tag in for Maven version. For example:

```
<plugin><artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.x.x</version>
   <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
</configuration></plugin>
```

See if that fixes it. The version should be whatever version of Maven you have installed.

Comment: thank you for the answer - I have tried it but new crash occurs - the version is not a key I think (

Answer (score 0):

I guess the java compiler found by Maven does not support 1.7. Hence, your 1.7 options are ignored and the 1.3 defaults are used. You need to fix your JAVA_HOME/PATH environment variables, or configure the right JDK using Maven Toolchains plugin.

Also, the version of maven-compiler-plugin and the version of maven core do not necessarily need to be the same. Your message indicates that this is the case.

If I were you, I'd run maven with -X flag and look for (a) the version of picked maven-compiler-plugin when you don't have the <version> tag, (b) which javac is picked up, and (c) what was the actual source level used for your project.

Comment: I have tried to define Java_home in mvn as:  JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/${JAVA_VERSION}/Home  and I have tried JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::") also I have used JAVA_HOME='java-config --jre-home'

Comment: @curiousity That looks like you're on Mac, so `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework` will only give you Apple JVMs and not Oracle ones, which means 1.6 at the latest.  For 1.7 you need to (a) be sure you've installed the _JDK_ from Oracle, not just the _JRE_ and (b) use `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*')`

Comment: If that's worked correctly your JAVA_HOME should point to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_NN.jdk/Contents/Home` for a suitable value of `NN`